# Stripe every 4 rows in table

Tags: html, css

I have a basic web app that has a datatable.

```html
<table id="period_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-sm display nowrap display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Problem:  I want to stripe my table 4 by 4. I mean first 4 row is gray, next 4 row is white then the next 4 row is gray again. "table-striped" class only stripes 1 by 1.

Comment: What pre processor are you using, please create a tag. And if you want to show us code we can use please ensure the table has enough rows to enable 4 coloured, 4 not etc.

Comment: @AHaworth they're most likely using tailwind css but theyll have to write their own to achieve their desired styling

Comment: I use datatables (datatables.net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `nth-child` with a series of formulas (`8n+k`), `n` start with 0 :

```
`8n+1` will select row 1 - 9 - 17 ...
`8n+2` will select row 2 - 10 - 18 ...
`8n+3` will select row 3 - 11 - 19 ...
`8n+4` will select row 4 - 12 - 20 ...
```

At the end we will come up with the desired result

```css
tbody > tr:nth-child(8n+1), 
tbody > tr:nth-child(8n+2),
tbody > tr:nth-child(8n+3),
tbody > tr:nth-child(8n+4) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="period_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-sm display nowrap display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```